# std::unique_ptr takes too much space when we add any data type

Tags: c++, std, smart-pointers

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    float f = 0.0f;
    double d1 = 0.0, d2 = 0.0, d3 = 0.0, d4 = 0.0;

    auto a = [i,f,d1,d2,d3,d4](){};

    std::cout << sizeof(std::unique_ptr<decltype(a)>) << std::endl;       //  8
    std::cout << sizeof(std::unique_ptr<char, decltype(a)>) << std::endl; // 48

    return 0;
}
```

Why the output of this program is 48 when I add just one char?

Comment: What do you think `std::unique_ptr<char, decltype(a)>` is?  In particular, what do each of the template arguments represent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why the output of this program is 48 when I add just one char?

Because you specify a deleter that contains an int a float and 4 doubles. That deleter is stored as a sub object of the unique pointer.

Note that such unique pointer wouldn't work in the first place since the deleter doesn't satisfy the necessary requirements. In particular, it doesn't accept the argument that would be passed into it.

Comment: *"that deleter would leak the allocated char"*. It would produce hard error, as deleter doesn't have correct signature for `operator()`

Comment: @Jarod42 Are functions taken into account with `sizeof()`? I'd doubt that.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: `sizeof` is indeed an un-evaluated context, so no methods are instantiated. The remark about the invalid deleter is for when it is actually instantiated and used. I just pinpointed that the invalidity is a compilation error before the memory leak.